# Running symfony 2 project in php built in web server

Tags: php, symfony, php-builtin-server

I'm trying to create and run a Symfony 2 (2.5) project on Netbeans with built in php web server, I've added the following router script.

```
> if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    return false;
} else {
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . 'app.php'
    ;
    require 'app.php';
}
```

However when I run the project it always returns the following response.

> Not Found
>   The requested resource / was not found on this server.

Could anyone advise? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, is apache2 mod_rewrite enabled ? check your routes with app/console router:debug

Comment: I'm trying to run on php built in web server. Not with Apache2.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Symfony the best way IMHO is to use Symfony's bundled script for built-in server. It works with command `php app/console server:run`.